# Buffering output in C without using FILE

Tags: html, c, memory, stream, buffer

I'm trying to create a full HTML result with HTTP headers with the correct size for content-length as simple as possible.

I looked at setbuf() function but it only works with streams, but I want to directly buffer the output to memory without having a disk involved. Is there a simpler function that does what I'm trying to achieve?

I know in php, one can use ob_start() to start buffering data and ob_get_contents() to load the data in memory and determine the size so is there anything like this in C that I can use?

```
int main(){
    char *mybuf=malloc(1048576); //Allocate 1MB memory for buffer
    char *mytitle="Webpage title";
    char *mydesc="This is a page version";
    int myver=2;
    //print HTTP header of known data
    printf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    printf("Server: Something\r\n");
    printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
    printf("Cache-control: no-cache\r\n");
    //Buffer HTML output to get size (we don't print these 4 lines yet)
    sprintf(mybuf,"<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n",mytitle);
    sprintf(mybuf+strlen(mybuf),"<h1>%s</h1>\r\n",mytitle);
    sprintf(mybuf+strlen(mybuf),"<p>%s %d</p>\r\n",mydesc,myver);
    sprintf(mybuf+strlen(mybuf),"</body></html>\r\n");
    //Print content length header with size of buffered data
    printf("Content-length: %d\r\n",strlen(mybuf));
    //then print the rest of the data
    printf("%s",mybuf);
    free(mybuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C language specification does not define any facility for streams backed only by memory, without any underlying file.  Your `sprintf()` based approach is not bad, but it could be improved by capturing and using the return value, which tells you how many characters were printed.  You could use this to avoid all the `strlen()` calls, which could be a considerable savings if the content is large, especially if it is printed in many small pieces:

```
size_t total_bytes_written = 0;
long rval;

rval = sprintf(mybuf, "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n", mytitle);
if (rval < 0) {
    // handle error ...
}
total_bytes_written += rval;

rval = sprintf(mybuf + total_bytes_written, "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n", mytitle);
// ...
```

---

Alternatively, if you are on a system that conforms to POSIX.1-2008 or later, and you are willing to limit your program to such systems, then you might find [`open_memstream()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) of interest.  This gives you a stream backed by a dynamically managed block of memory.  You would write to it with `fprintf()` or other stream IO functions, and when done, read back a pointer to the data and the total size.  Something like this:

```
char *buf_ptr = NULL;
size_t buf_size = 0;
FILE *mem = open_memstream(&buf_ptr, &buf_size);

fprintf(mem, "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n", mytitle);
fprintf(mem, "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n", mytitle);

// ...

fclose(mem);  // mandatory
printf("Content-length: %d\r\n", buf_size);
printf("%s", buf_ptr);  // the data are guaranteed null-terminated
free(buf);  // you are responsible for this
```

(All error checks omitted for brevity.)

This relieves you of the manual size tracking, and it gains you a dynamically-growing backing buffer so that you can handle both large and small outputs with reasonable memory efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length, as you probably know, is the size of your body.  This means you have to know at least the length of the body before you can generate the header (or use chunked transfer).  sprintf returns the number of bytes written, either accumulate those, or squash it into a single call:

```
int n = snprintf(mybuf,
  mybuf_len,
  "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n"
  ...
  "</body></html>\r\n",
  mytitle, ..., myver
);
```

Then generate the header(n) with the n you figured out.  If you pass in NULL for instead of mybuf, you get a size without writing anything, then you could do another write a pass in header with the count you got from the first call.  If you want, wrap this in a function or two:

```
int response(const char *header, int body_len, const char body[body_len]) {
   ...
}
```

Consider picking a template library (I like the mustache format).  It's kinda messy and error prune doing this by hand with raw strings.  You have a 1 MB buffer allocated there but use like a .5k, and you will shoot yourself in the foot one day anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem:

- your approach is OK, but you should use `snprintf()` to avoid potential buffer overflows:

  ```
    int main() {
        char *mybuf = malloc(1048576); //Allocate 1MB memory for buffer
        const char *mytitle = "Webpage title";
        const char *mydesc = "This is a page version";
        int myver = 2;
        size_t pos = 0;
        //print HTTP header of known data
        printf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        printf("Server: Something\r\n");
        printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
        printf("Cache-control: no-cache\r\n");
        //Buffer HTML output to get size (we don't print these 4 lines yet)
        pos += snprintf(mybuf + pos, pos < sizeof mybuf ? sizeof mybuf - pos : 0,
                        "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n", mytitle);
        pos += snprintf(mybuf + pos, pos < sizeof mybuf ? sizeof mybuf - pos : 0,
                        "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n", mytitle);
        pos += snprintf(mybuf + pos, pos < sizeof mybuf ? sizeof mybuf - pos : 0,
                        "<p>%s %d</p>\r\n", mydesc, myver);
        pos += snprintf(mybuf + pos, pos < sizeof mybuf ? sizeof mybuf - pos : 0,
                        "</body></html>\r\n");
        //Print content length header with size of buffered data
        printf("Content-length: %zu\r\n", pos);
        printf("\r\n");
        //then print the rest of the data
        printf("%s", mybuf);
        free(mybuf);
        return 0;
    }
  ```
- Here is a simpler one, combining the calls and using `snprintf` to compute the length:

  ```
    int main() {
        const char *mytitle = "Webpage title";
        const char *mydesc = "This is a page version";
        int myver = 2;
        size_t length = 0;
        //print HTTP header of known data
        printf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        printf("Server: Something\r\n");
        printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
        printf("Cache-control: no-cache\r\n");
        //Buffer HTML output to get size (we don't print these 4 lines yet)
        length = snprintf(NULL, 0,
                         "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n" 
                         "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n"
                         "<p>%s %d</p>\r\n"
                         "</body></html>\r\n",
                         mytitle, mytitle, mydesc, myver);
        //Print content length header with size of buffered data
        printf("Content-length: %zu\r\n", length);
        printf("\r\n");
        //then print the rest of the data
        printf("<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n" 
               "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n"
               "<p>%s %d</p>\r\n"
               "</body></html>\r\n",
               mytitle, mytitle, mydesc, myver);
        return 0;
    }
  ```
- you could use `open_memstream()` as explained by *John Bollinger*:

  ```
    int main() {
        const char *mytitle = "Webpage title";
        const char *mydesc = "This is a page version";
        int myver = 2;
        size_t length = 0;
        char *buf_ptr = NULL;
        size_t buf_size = 0;  // the buffer size
        int length = 0;       // the length of the output
        FILE *mem = open_memstream(&buf_ptr, &buf_size);

        //print HTTP header of known data
        printf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        printf("Server: Something\r\n");
        printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
        printf("Cache-control: no-cache\r\n");
        //Buffer HTML output to get size (we don't print these 4 lines yet)
        if (mem == NULL) {
            // Deal with the error
            printf("Internal error\r\n");
            return 1;
        }
        length = fprintf(mem,
                         "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n" 
                         "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n"
                         "<p>%s %d</p>\r\n"
                         "</body></html>\r\n",
                         mytitle, mytitle, mydesc, myver);
        //Print content length header with size of buffered data
        printf("Content-length: %zu\r\n", length);
        printf("\r\n");
        //then print the rest of the data
        //beware that buf_ptr is not necessarily null terminated
        printf("%.*s", length, buf_ptr);
        //could also use fwrite(f, buf_ptr, 1, length, stdout);
        free(buf_ptr);
        return 0;
    }
  ```
- you can implement your own `mem_printf()` that allocates or reallocates a memory buffer:

  ```
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int mem_printf(char **bufp, size_t *lenp, const char *fmt, ...) {
        char buf[1024];
        va_list ap;
        char *newbuf;
        int len;

        va_start(ap, fmt);
        len = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        if (len < 0)
            return -1;
        newbuf = realloc(*bufp, *lenp + len + 1);
        if (newbuf == NULL)
            return -1;
        *bufp = newbuf;
        if ((size_t)len < sizeof buf) {
            memcpy(newbuf + *lenp, buf, len + 1);
        } else {
            va_start(ap, fmt);
            vsnprintf(newbuf + *lenp, len + 1, fmt, ap);
            va_end(ap);
        }
        *lenp += len;
        return len;
    }

    int main() {
        const char *mytitle = "Webpage title";
        const char *mydesc = "This is a page version";
        int myver = 2;
        char *buf_ptr = NULL;
        size_t buf_len = 0;

        //print HTTP header of known data
        printf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
        printf("Server: Something\r\n");
        printf("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
        printf("Cache-control: no-cache\r\n");
        //Buffer HTML output to get size (we don't print these 4 lines yet)
        mem_printf(&buf_ptr, &buf_len,
                   "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>\r\n"
                   "<h1>%s</h1>\r\n"
                   "<p>%s %d</p>\r\n"
                   "</body></html>\r\n",
                   mytitle, mytitle, mydesc, myver);
        //Print content length header with size of buffered data
        printf("Content-length: %zu\r\n", buf_len);
        printf("\r\n");
        //then print the rest of the data
        fputs(buf_ptr, stdout);
        free(buf_ptr);
        return 0;
    }
  ```